# Java ArrayList.clear() function

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
temp.add(5);temp.add(6);
result.add(temp);
temp.clear();
```

I wrote codes like something above, what puzzles me is when I debug the code, I found the result contains size of 1 but the values (5,6,...) are lost after I applying the clear function, can any one explain why?

Comment: You didn't clear the result list, so it will still have one element (an empty list).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo it seems the person just wants to delete one item of the 2D list?

Comment: Sorry my intention is to clear the temp not the result list. I mean after clearing the members in the temp, even the result's list is affected

Comment: Can you tell us what result were you expecting exactly? It is not very clear in the question

Answer (score 5):

You have list of lists. After this code

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
temp.add(5);temp.add(6);
result.add(temp);
```

situation looks like this

```
                     ┌───> 5
result ─────> tmp ───┤
                     └───> 6
```

- `result` list contains one element which is `tmp` list
- `tmp` list contains two elements `5` and `6`

after

```
temp.clear();
```

situation changes to

```
           // ↓↓↓ `temp.clear()` affects only this list
result ─────> tmp
```

so now

- `tmp` list is empty
- but `result` *still contains `tmp` list* that is why its size is 1

Comment: +1 for the graphical representation of the situation :)

Answer (score 1):

This line of code

```
result.add(temp);
```

Adds a reference to `temp` to result, the next line

```
temp.clear(); // <-- here
```

clears temp. I think you wanted a copy of `temp` (so that you could then clear `temp` without altering `result`) so,

```
result.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(temp)); // <-- copy temp.
```

Then clearing `temp` will not change the values in `result`.

Comment: I've no idea what's the difference between deep and normal/

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah, this explains my confusion well. I don't even know the reference thing would happen in java

Comment: @i3wangyi normal copies one level.  deep copies all levels.

Comment: @i3wangyi: A deep copy copies all the elements too. This creates a new `List` that still contains the same `Integer` references.

Comment: @Elliott: Yep, I think this answers the question well. +1

Answer (score 1):

`temp` is a *reference* to an ArrayList object.

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp;
```

This add the *reference* to the result List.

```
result.add(temp);  // adds a copy of the reference, not a copy of the list.
```

This clear the original and only list (apart from the `result` list)

```
temp.clear();
```

Note: Java only has `references` and `primitives`, there is no other types.

> How could I do to avoid this situation? copy the temp list?

for every new list you want, create a new one.  Instead of temp.clear() call

```
temp = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ideally, you shouldn't even reuse the local variable unless it has the same purpose.

```
// don't use temp again.
List<Integer> temp2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

BTW I advocate that you re-use mutable objects to maximise performance. You should only do this after you have measured this a problem for your allocation rate and you know what you are doing.

Comment: thanks @peter How could I do to avoid this situation? copy the temp list?